# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Capacity: -102 when reading a large parquet file by pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a large parquet file (~5GB) and I want to load it in spark. The following command executes without any error:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("path/to/file.parquet")
```

But when I try to do any operation like `.show()` or `.repartition(n)` I run into the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Capacity: -102
```

any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an integer overflow bug in the underlying parquet reader. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1633

Upgrade PySpark to 3.2.1. The jar file parquet-hadoop-1.12.2 contains the code/actual fix.